# CS1061: Compilation Error Message (Grid view error)

Tags: asp.net

Everything was running smoothly until I tried to test out my asp page in chrome for the 1000th time and this time it gave me this error and I cant seem to find whats wrong

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged1' and no extension method 'GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged1' accepting a first argument of type 'default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"      DataKeyNames="ISBN" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged1">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a method for the event GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged1 in the code behind (the default.aspx.cs) file.

```
protected void GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Thank you! That was part of it, after leaving it alone for the evening and looking at it with fresh eyes, I put a 1 at the end of "SelectedIndexChanged1"  the 1 being my mouse has 6 numbers on it and I must have clicked that when my cursor was in place. Thank you though!